# beginner trying to implement a timer in a for loop c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, timer

I'm very new to c# and coding in general and am having some problems implementing a timer in a for loop. Basically, the bit of code below is trying to create a number representative of trash output by an island at set intervals, with each output weighted based on island population to be a bit less predictable. it then adds the generated trash figure to a total. The problem I'm having is that the way tutorials use the Timer class means creating an `'Intervaltimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)'` function outside of `Main()` and I can't work out how to then add whatever is generated by this back to the `weights[]` array in the `Main()`.  All I really want to do is as soon as the compiler goes into the for loop, tell it to wait 'x' ticks, then continue. Thread.Sleep isn't an option because this is to go in unity, so would interrupt other things. apologies if the code below is a bit gory!

```
{
class Program
{
    public static double trashperstan8 = 600 * 3.21;
    public static int population = 1000;
    public static double trashperpersperday = 1;
    public static double interval = 60;
    public static double intperday = 1440 / interval;
    public static double trashperint = population * trashperpersperday * (interval / 1440);
    public static int weightnum = population / 200;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double Trashlevel = new double();
        double stand8sfilled = new double();
        Timer intervaltimer = new Timer((interval / 30) * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine(weightnum);

        for (int inti = 0; inti < intperday; inti++)
        {
            /* at this point, I want to basically tell the code: each time you go 
               through the for loop, wait for x number of ticks then do the method */

            Console.WriteLine(inti);

            double[] weights = new double[weightnum];

            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < weightnum; i++)
            {
                double weightcontrib = rand.NextDouble();

                weights[i] = weightcontrib;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Array.IndexOf(weights, weightcontrib), weightcontrib);
            }

            double finalweight = 2 * (weights.Sum() / weightnum);
            Console.WriteLine("final weight " + finalweight);

            double weightedtpi = trashperint * finalweight;

            Trashlevel = Trashlevel + weightedtpi;

            stand8sfilled = stand8sfilled + (weightedtpi / trashperstan8);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("trash level " + Trashlevel);
        Console.WriteLine("stand8s filled " + stand8sfilled);
    }

    private static void Intervaltimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use Thread.Sleep((interval / 30) * 1000);

Comment: `weights` is a local variable. It can't be updated from outside `Main()` (unless it is [closed](https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/)). You might consider declaring it outside of `Main` so that it becomes a member variable.

Comment: I see you're using a big loop for `inti`. The `inti` variable isn't used at all. What if you move the code in the loop to the timer and create a field inti which you increment in the timer. Like John said, the weights should be a field

Comment: @SaileshChowdaryDoppalapudi unfortunately i can't use sleep because this will eventually go into unity when fixed. thanks for the answer though, question amended!

Comment: @J.vanLangen don't I need `inti` just to have the for loop cycle through?

Comment: @Alec if you want some delay between iteration, you could use the timer for the 'iteration'. It only should repeat the inner code of the inti loop.

Comment: @JohnWu I dont really want/need to keep `weights` though. I just want the for the smaller for loop to produce a value for `weight`, apply it to `trashperint`, and then it can be disposed of once `trashperint` has been added to `trashlevel` and the loop big loop starts again.

Comment: Note that there are many problems with your existing code. In particular, the `new Random` needs to be called outside the loop, and preferably a static member of the class. You almost never want to make more than one Random per thread in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All I really want to do is as soon as the compiler goes into the for loop, tell it to wait 'x' ticks, then continue. Thread.Sleep isn't an option because this is to go in unity, so would interrupt other things.

Solution 1: Don't write a loop at all. **The timer already is logically a loop**.

- Write a method that is the "body" of the "loop".
- "Starting the loop" is activating a timer where the body method is the event handler and the timer fires every n milliseconds
- "Terminating the loop" is deactivating the timer.

Solution 2: Write a loop, don't use a timer.

Make the method `async` and then `await Task.Delay(whatever);` to *asynchronously* wait for your delay.  Your method will suspend when it hits the await, and resume at some point after the delay task is complete.

The latter is probably the better solution in that the code more closely resembles your description of it.

I don't know enough about Unity to say which is the better solution in their framework.

Comment: I agree 100% this is almost always the right pattern. But this is the `Main` method of a console program, there's no synchronization context, and there's nothing else, async or otherwise, going on in the program. Isn't this maybe one of the few cases where a `Sleep()` call is actually the right answer?

Comment: @JohnWu: The OP addressed that in a comment: "unfortunately i can't use sleep because this will eventually go into unity when fixed."

Comment: @JohnWu: This is one of the reasons why it is a bad idea to prototype GUI code in a console app.  But to answer your question, yes, if you genuinely have a single-threaded console app and you genuinely need to introduce a delay, then sleeping might be appropriate. Certainly more appropriate than busy-waiting. :-)

Comment: @EricLippert using the timer as a loop has done the trick, thanks! I hadn't thought about it like that, so thanks for the hint.